# Using Checkboxes in UITableViewCell - when the checkbox and the cell behaviour must be different

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, checkbox

I have been following the steps in this question: 
[How to add a checkbox to a UITableView on the left, while using UITableViewCell caching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699902/how-to-add-a-checkbox-to-a-uitableview-on-the-left-while-using-uitableviewcell)

I don't want a simple check box that gets checked if a row is tapped, I need a check box that changes **only when the checkbox is tapped**, since the cell itself already loads a detailed view for the selected item.

- How can I "move" the cell to the right, to be able to see the checked button properly? (solved this one: in Storyboard, select the cell, go to Attributes Inspector, and change the width of the identation)
- What should I use for the tags, since *indexPath.row* does not work? If I select the first item, it checks the 8th(solved this one in the selected answer)

**UPDATE: Even though I selected an answer as correct, it only solved my problem partially. The checked items are moved to the end of the section when the view is reloaded, instead of keeping the same order they had previously. Anyone knows why?**

[image: screen of this situation]

Here is the updated code for cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView2 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell2"];
UIButton *checkBox;
if (cell.tag == 0) {
    checkBox = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, 20, 20)];
    UIImage *normalImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"unchecked.png"];
    UIImage *selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"checked.png"];
    [checkBox setImage:normalImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [checkBox setImage:selectedImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [checkBox addTarget:self action:@selector(makeWatched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:checkBox];
    cell.tag = 1;
}

for (id obj in cell.contentView.subviews) {
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        checkBox = obj;
        checkBox.tag = indexPath.row;
        break;
    }
}


Episodi *epi = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];


 checkBox.selected = ([self.selectedChecks containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:  (indexPath.row)]])? YES : NO;

if ([epi.watched isEqualToString:@"1"]) {

    NSLog(@"Entra");
    checkBox.selected = YES;

}

cell.textLabel.text = epi.episodeTitle;
return cell;
```

}

Updated code for the checkbox action:

```
-(void)makeWatched:(UIButton *) checkButton {
    if (checkButton.selected == NO) {

       Episodi *epi = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:checkButton.tag inSection:sectionNumber]];
       [epi setWatched:@"1"];
       checkButton.selected=YES;
       NSError *error = nil;
       if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
           NSLog(@"Saving changes failed: %@", error);
       } else {
        // The changes have been persisted.
    }

    [self.selectedChecks addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(checkButton.tag)]];


    [self.tableView2 reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:checkButton.tag inSection:sectionNumber]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];



}else{

    Episodi *epi = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:checkButton.tag inSection:sectionNumber]];
    [epi setWatched:@"0"];
    if ([epi.watched isEqualToString:@"0"]){
       NSLog(@"Not Watched anymore");
    }
    checkButton.selected=NO;
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Saving changes failed: %@", error);
    } else {
        // The changes have been persisted.
    }


    [self.selectedChecks removeObjectIdenticalTo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(checkButton.tag)]];
    [self.tableView2 reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:checkButton.tag inSection:sectionNumber]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
  }
 }
```

Comment: Even though my initial question was about checking/unchecking elements, I'm having trouble pairing that with the variable "Watched" that I have for every episode. Apparently, this should be pretty easy, I just check wether watched is 1 or 0, and if it's 1, I check the button, so I can keep track even if I close the app. I'll add the updated code that I have for that, but it doesn't show the selected episodes at app launch (plus when I check stuff, the order of the episodes gets mixed up)

Comment: what is the use checkBox.selected = ([self.selectedChecks containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:  (indexPath.row)]])? YES : NO; this method?

Comment: where define self.selectedChecks method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you're doing wrong is adding more than one check box in a cell. You enter the "else" clause if the cell is not nil -- that cell already has a checkbox with its tag. You then add another checkbox to that cell with its own tag.

You should refactor your code to only do the addition of any subviews when the cell is nil. Anything having to do with the content, including the checkbox's tags should be done outside of the if clause.

**After Edit:**

Here is one way to do it. I wrap the creation of the checkbox in an if statement so that only one checkbox is ever added to a cell (the newly created cell will have the default tag value of 0). I have an array, selectedChecks, that hold the row of all the checked boxes (remember to create that array in viewDidLoad).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    UIButton *checkBox;
    if (cell.tag == 0) {
        checkBox = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-5, 10, 20, 20)];
        UIImage *normalImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Uncheck.png"];
        UIImage *selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Check.png"];
        [checkBox setImage:normalImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [checkBox setImage:selectedImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [checkBox addTarget:self action:@selector(makeWatched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:checkBox];
        cell.tag = 1;
    }

    for (id obj in cell.contentView.subviews) {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            checkBox = obj;
            checkBox.tag = indexPath.row;
            break;
        }
    }
    checkBox.selected = ([self.selectedChecks containsObject:@(indexPath.row)])? YES : NO;
    cell.textLabel.text =  self.theData[indexPath.row];       
    return cell;
}


-(void)makeWatched:(UIButton *) checkButton {
    if (checkButton.selected == NO) {
        [self.selectedChecks addObject:@(checkButton.tag)];
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:checkButton.tag inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }else{
        [self.selectedChecks removeObjectIdenticalTo:@(checkButton.tag)];
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:checkButton.tag inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }
}
```

This should work, but I think it's easier to create a custom class for your cell and add the button in the storyboard, and have an IBOutlet to that button in your custom cell .h file.

Comment: I've checked and I never enter the "cell== nil" part, maybe because I reuse identifiers?

Comment: Also if I create the Button inside the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method, I can't use it in the event "makeWatched" method. But if I declare it outisde that method, it doesn't work either.

Comment: @Elbereth, whether you enter the cell == nil clause depends on how you make the cell. If the cell comes from a storyboard, then the cell is never nil. I can add some code that I think will work, but what behavior do you want? Can more than one checkbox be selected at a time?

Comment: Yes, the cell is created in Storyboard , and it is a custom cell. Yes, I have to be able to check multiple checkboxes, and they should stay checked always, until the user unchecks it. I have a Watched attribute for every episode, so I can keep track of that.  Every cell is an episode. The behavior should be that if I tap the cell, it loads information for that episode (this part already works) and if I check the checkbox, it must stay checked until unchecked. Yes I'm interested in that code.

Comment: There should be a way to change the attribute Watched for en Episode to YES or NO, when the checkbox is checked/unchecked

Comment: I've copied the code but everytime there's a "@" (for example @(indexPath.row)) it shows a compilation error "Unexpected @ in program". If I delete it then I get another error

Comment: @Elbereth, what version of Xcode are you using? That's the new NSNumber literal syntax. You can replace it with [NSNumber numberWithInt:]. And where there's an array, arr[whatever], it can be replaced by [arr objectAtIndex:whatever].

Comment: I'm using Xcode 4.3 and ios5, because I can't update from snow leopard :( I'll try that now

Comment: Sorry to bother, but although I could change   [self.selectedChecks addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(checkButton.tag)]] I cannot figure out how to change the @ in [self.tableView2 reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:checkButton.tag inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

Comment: @Elbereth, [self.tableView2 reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:checkButton.tag inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

Comment: Thank you very much. It works fine now, but I will have to do some work because I have sections in my table and when I check the 1st item in a section, it also checks it in every other section.

Comment: This works for checking unchecking elements. If I want to keep track of that when the app closes, I've added and edit and edited the code for what I'm trying to do now.

Comment: where define/which type( self.selectedChecks) this method?

Answer (score 2):

You should create a subclass of UITableViewCell and use xib to layout the checkboxes and labels in the custom cell. Use the custom UITableViewCell in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. With that way, your custom checkbox will be cached instead of being recreated every time. You will still need to set the value of the check box (selected or not) in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Checkout this tutorial to see how to create custom UITableViewCell using xib: http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.sg/2012/10/uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder.html

Comment: Is it possible to do this without making any other .xib files? It looks like a very long process, plus I wouldn't like that to interfere with the whole table view, which works perfectly. I only need to select the correct index when I check the image.

Comment: In cellForRowAtIndexPath, call `checkBox.selected = indexPathIsSelected;`. `indexPathIsSelected` is a BOOL that fulfills the condition. You will need an `NSMutableSet` or `NSMutableArray` of selected indexPaths so that you can use something like `[selectedSet containsObject:indexPath]` or `[selectedArray indexOfObject:indexPath] != NSNotFound`

Comment: I could use indexPath directly, the thing is that it doesn't seem to be of use in the checkbox tag.